# How to extract certain string characters in Javascript in a generic way?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to extract a string value, but I need a generic code to extract the values.

```
INPUT 1 : "/rack=1/shelf=1/slot=12/port=200"
INPUT 2 : "/shelf=1/slot=13/port=3"
INPUT 3 : "/shelf=1/slot=142/subslot=2/port=4"
```

I need the below output:

```
OUTPUT 1 : "/rack=1/shelf=1/slot=12"
OUTPUT 2 : "/shelf=1/slot=13"
OUTPUT 3 : "/shelf=1/slot=142"
```

Basically I am trying to extract up to the slot value. I tried `indexOf` and `substr`, but those are specific to individual string values. I require a generic code to extract up to slot. Is there a way how I can match the numeric after the slot and perform extraction?

Comment: Should OUTPUT 1 be `"/rack=1/shelf=1/slot=12"`? And the keyword you are looking for is [tag:regex].

Comment: Yes. i updated the output with "/rack=1/shelf=1/slot=12"

Answer (score 1):

We can try matching on the following regular expression, which captures all content we want to appear in the output:

```regex
^(.*\/shelf=\d+\/slot=\d+).*$
```

Note that this greedily captures all content up to, and including, the `/shelf` followed by `/slot` portions of the input path.

```js
var inputs = ["/rack=1/shelf=1/slot=12/port=200", "/shelf=1/slot=13/port=3", "/shelf=1/slot=142/subslot=2/port=4"];
for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    var output = inputs[i].replace(/^(.*\/shelf=\d+\/slot=\d+).*$/, "$1");
    console.log(inputs[i] + " => " + output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function. If `"subslot"` is always after `"slot"` then you can remove the `"/"` in `indexOf("/slot")`

```
function exractUptoSlot(str) {
    return str.substring(0,str.indexOf("/",str.indexOf("/slot")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it will always be the last substring, you could use `slice`:

```
function removeLastSubStr(str, delimiter) {
  const splitStr = str.split(delimiter);

  return splitStr
    .slice(0, splitStr.length - 1)
    .join(delimiter);
}

const str = "/rack=1/shelf=1/slot=12/port=200";

console.log(
  removeLastSubStr(str, '/')
)
```

if you don't know where your substring is, but you know what it is you could `filter` it out of the split array:

```
function removeSubStr(str, delimiter, substr) {
  const splitStr = str.split(delimiter);

  return splitStr
    .filter(s => !s.contains(substr))
    .join(delimiter);
}

const str = "/rack=1/shelf=1/slot=12/port=200";

console.log(
  removeSubStr(str, '/', 'port=200')
)

console.log(
  removeSubStr(str, '/', 'port')
)
```